# How can I make myself read a question before judging it?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I often accuse other members in not reading a question before starting an answer or action.

The problem is - I often follow the same pattern; and I can't help it. Making yourself accustomed to something will inevitably make you fast to judge, catching the meaning by the glimpse of few keywords, in less than a second, really. Especially if 99% of questions are the same dull mindless trash, repeated in great numbers every day all year round.

But the devil is in the detail, you know and it's especially sorrowful when, due this habit, you miss - or even misjudge and downvote - a good question showing some research or even a glimpse of thought behind it, as such questions are extremely rare.

So, is there a technique that makes you actually read the question through before judging it?

Comment: Use your common sense.

Comment: This is going to be one of those crappy Meta posts again, isn't it? Ah well, let's read it anyway ... ;)

Comment: @Bart I can't help upvoting your comment :)

Comment: *Votes to migrate to cognitive science SE*

Comment: I might already have @LowerClassOverflowian .... *checks* nope, I didn't.

Comment: I think "99% of questions are the same dull mindless trash" is quite an overstatement. Yes, there's quite a lot of bad questions but not nearly that many.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I think the word you seek is "instinct" ;) it's prevalent in all animals. The "big animal that looks like a Tiger" is ready to fight us too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see your issue, as you obviously help out a lot and after a while (certainly in the PHP tag) one gets sick of reading the same old questions.
Even if different questions it's the *same old* in terms of user is asking something Google would answer (probably from the meta desc text), or they're on a very basic level and should still be reading books and/or searching Google, etc.
e.g.
"Why isn't my $_session working?"  "I get a blank white page"...  Or "This code doesn't work.."
The latter are harder to help with as one has to read the entire code, and usually to find it was a #*%%ing stupid problem that a quick search would have resolved.

This is by no means a rant, and anyone who frequents PHP tag will agree due to the high frequency of these very poor questions (dunno if other tags are the same, however).

So it's likely a lot of people's tolerance is lowered.
It's a shame as the site gives us the tools to deal with this (votes, comments, flags), and if everyone used them the site would improve as people see certain things are not tolerated and stop posting crap (to a degree, of course).

But sadly, the crap questions are tolerated, as there's *always* at least one user who will give an answer to a schmucky question.

---

> So, is there a technique that makes you actually read the question through before judging it?

So rather than read the entire question every time, I generally have a *very quick* glance first to see if there is something obvious lurking which would make me not want to help.
Such as:

1. Is the question an *obvious* dupe and user has not bothered searching (I know this quickly from frequenting the PHP tag, am sure you're the same here);
2. Is there an actual question, coherent, and with code, details, what doesn't happen, what should happen (at least to a degree whereby I can see the issue and provide an answer/comment without spending a lot of my time deciphering due to their lack of effort);
3. What their rep is. While this has no immediate bearing on my
   decisions, if it's a border-line weak question, and they've
   contributed a bit to the site (answered/asked/etc) then I let a *bit*
   slip, if they have (what is usually) a fat 1 rep and asking "fix my
   codez pleeze" then I downvote, tell them to make some effort.

On 3. I flag if it's bag enough. Though if I lowered my threshold for when I flag even a tiny amount, I'd be raising flags all day.

The above list may seem a lot, but I've gotten into the habit/rhythm now so usually I've got enough info within 5-10 seconds as to whether I'm going to either help, or downvote/flag and use a pre-saved comment (clippings).

Other than this, I'm even happy to help basic questions from noobs, as long as it's not something Stack and the internet is full of support and info for. But I agree with CommonSense.
And not only is it annoying raking through the crap, it lowers one's tolerance and thus the lazy users' questions likely hinder our helping noobs due to our tolerance already being drained.
It is affecting the site. Users getting a dirty vote or two here and there answering a poor question knowing the OP and other lazy/noobs will whack them a vote to keep them going and answering other questions they likely need answering.

> Especially if 99% of questions are the same dull mindless trash, repeated in great numbers every day all year round.

I frequent PHP, and not sure about other tags, but there are a lot of dirty questions in PHP. User posting quickly for their answer, with no effort whatsoever on their behalf.

It's *usually* someone saying "this code doesn't work for some reason" ie their redirect wont work/no sessions, etc.

I find myself getting annoyed at people answering questions which should simply have downvotes and comments like "no effort on your part, try yourself first and tell us your specific issue".

There is no way to resolve this issue, other than users downvote the answers because they shouldn't have answered, but this is impossible as there seems to be an unwritten rule that one cannot dvote an answer on a poor question if it's a good answer.
I disagree, I think people should downvote an answer, good or bad, if it's on a really poor question! The downvote is because they're showing other users "this sort of crap is acceptable" - please continue to ignore the help and support and rules and simply post crap and someone will answer you!

Comment: You will never succeed with the latter either. Greed (for rep points) advocated by charity (we're helping people!) makes absolutely impenetrable armor.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about judging it before reading. Everybody does so to some extent. Don't act on that judgement until you've read it though.

If you vote (up or down) or vote to close based on an unread post, you're doing it wrong. Take your time to actually read the post before you do that. But quick judgement often helps me to find posts that need attention, or to ignore posts I'm most likely not going to be interested in. And there's not much wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think that the habit of glossing-over is a useful developed habit. Truth is, you *can* gloss over a ton of stuff.

The solution? Do not be trigger happy in voting. Reserve voting for whenever you are *confident* in your vote.

The comment is an implicit vote also. Often, you can leave a  commment that behaves like a vote. It will push the user to fix something, or encourage another to vote a certain way.

If we all commented a little more, and voteda  little less - I think it's a fair proposition